# Extract multiple columns from nested lists (using object prefix)

Tags: r, nested-lists

I have several nested lists inside one common list.
I want to extract and store in one unique df all values from some specific columns (`col1`, `col2`, `col3` - it's always the second element in the nested list) within specific objects (all lists starting with `t.out` or `b.out`).

ReprEx below:

```
mylist<-list(par1 = rnorm(1,0,1)
         , par2 = rnorm(1,0,1)
         , par3 = rnorm(1,0,1)
         , par4 = rnorm(1,0,1)
         , t.out1 = list(val1 = rnorm(1,2,1)
                         , col1 = as.data.frame(rnorm(10,0,1)))
         , t.out2 = list(val2 = rnorm(1,2,1)
                         , col2 = as.data.frame(rnorm(10,0,1)))
         , b.out3 = list(val3 = rnorm(1,2,1)
                         , col3 = as.data.frame(rnorm(10,0,1)))
         , g.out4 = list(val4 = rnorm(1,2,1)
                         , col4 = as.data.frame(rnorm(10,0,1))))
```

I know how to extract the elements I need one by one using (example) `mylist[["t.out1"]][[2]]`, but I need some script that allows me to do it for many nested lists.

I tried with the following, but it doesn't work

```
select_lists <- names(mylist)[grep("^t.*$|^b.*$", names(mylist))]
mylist[[select_lists]][[2]]
```

`Error in mylist[[select_lists]] : no such index at level 2`

The expected result should look like the following

```
bind_cols(mylist[["t.out1"]][[2]]
          , mylist[["t.out2"]][[2]]
          , mylist[["b.out3"]][[2]])
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is and not just show your attempt assuming that the attempt implicitly describes the problem.  What is the input and what is the output?

Comment: Hi @G.Grothendieck, thanks for your reply.  I guess I can summarize the problem into the following statement: mylist is the output of a function that I have created. From mylist, I want to create a df using some particular columns stored into nested lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
sapply(mylist[grep("^(t|b)\\.out", names(mylist))],
 function(x) unlist(x[startsWith(names(x), "col")], use.names = FALSE))
#          t.out1     t.out2      b.out3
# [1,] -0.6741380  0.4457036  0.09194051
# [2,]  0.8463555 -1.0284650  0.23858507
# [3,] -1.9122132  0.9740014 -0.16088752
# [4,] -1.4880384 -0.2844162  2.32278847
# [5,]  0.6463312 -0.4652480 -1.04187252
# [6,] -1.2264961  0.7801192 -0.83594572
# [7,]  0.4658511 -0.7364893 -0.75425093
# [8,]  1.7240282 -1.4285961  1.97459931
# [9,]  0.6239692 -0.6896502 -1.64462726
#[10,] -1.0699496  0.3033302  0.34368145
```

with `mylist[grep("^(t|b)\\.out", names(mylist))]` I select those starting with *t.out* or *b.out*. With `startsWith(names(x), "col")` I get those staring with *col*.

Comment: Hi @GKi, thanks for your reply. This definitely solves the question asked - Is there any way to look for element number 2 in the list, rather than refer to its name "col"? (I am asking this since my real list hasn't any name assigned to those objects)

Comment: Try: `do.call(cbind, lapply(mylist[grep("^(t|b)\\.out", names(mylist))], "[[", 2))`